# Getting the row with the smallest column value if another column is the same in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, greatest-n-per-group

```
Id  Number  Value
------------------
1     6       1
2     6       2
3     9       2
```

I have a table like this and basically, I need to return the row with the smallest `Value` if their `Number` columns are the same, the example result I need is as below:

```
Id  Number  Value
-----------------
1     6       1
3     9       2
```

How do I achieve this in T-SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `rank` window function:

```
SELECT id, number, value
FROM   (SELECT id, number, value, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY number ORDER BY value) AS rk
        FROM   mytable)
WHERE  rk = 1
```

**EDIT:**
As noted in the comments, if there is more than one line with the lowest `value`, using `rank` would return both. If you want to return just one of them, you should use `row_number` instead:

```
SELECT id, number, value
FROM   (SELECT id, number, value,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY number ORDER BY value) AS rn
        FROM   mytable)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: Hey, your solution seems to work, but there one little problem I have with it, how would you handle it if the 'value's are the same with some and you just need to pick any of them, because it seems like this shows both rows even if the values are the same

Comment: Yes, I literally found it as soon as you replied, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Suhrahj If you want to choose just one of these rows, you could use `row_number` instead of `rank`. See my edited answer.

Comment: @Suhrahj, Similar was `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES id, number, value FROM mytable ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(PARTITION BY number ORDER BY value)`. But this avoids the sub-select...

Comment: I was curious and tested it. I must admit, that the solution with `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES` performs the `sort` twice. Once to computed `ROW_NUMBER` and again to find `TOP 1 WITH TIES`. The approach with `sub-select` (or `cte`) is faster...

Comment: @Shnugo thanks for the update and also trying it yourself before I saw it!